# Git error Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git, merge, rebase

**I faced this issue for many times, so I want to share with you to get what's wrong with my approach.**

I have two branches in the remote repository, `dev` and `master`. `dev` was originated from the `master` and have got 2 new commits.  (which is common)

Now I wanted to update remote `dev` branch with a few more commits and make a merge request to update the remote `master` branch eventually.

So I did the following

1. Fetched and checked out `dev`. e.g: `git fetch & git checkout dev`
2. Committed two times to local `dev`, in the meanwhile remote `master` was updated by another team mate and it has 3 new commits
3. So I checked out local `master` and pulled the latest origin `master`. e.g: `git checkout master & git pull origin master`
4. After the pull, I rebased the local `dev` against the local `master`.
   e.g:  `git rebase master dev`
5. And I pushed my local `dev` to the remote `dev`. e.g: `git push origin dev`

But it gave me an error
**`Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.`**

Even though `git push -f` will work, as far as I understood, my local `dev` was originated from the remote `dev` and has new commits, so it can't be behind the remote one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my local dev was originated from the remote dev and has new commits, so it can't be behind the remote one.

Yes it can and it is, in the sense that Git means it.

> After the pull, I rebased the local dev against the local master. e.g: git rebase master dev

That's the reason. Rebasing changes history. Simply, it replaces the rebased commits with new ones. You cannot move a commit, ever, not with rebase or anything else; you can only copy the commit as a different commit. It may have the same commit *message* but that's just part of what was copied.

Do you see? No? Okay, let's start before your step 1, where dev split off from master and had two new commits. Call those commits A and B. It was like that on the remote, and (1) you fetched and checked out that, so it was like that on your local dev too: your dev has the same A and B since the split from master.

(Now ignore everything else you did locally with dev...)

Then (2) master grew and (3) you pulled it and (4) rebased dev onto it. That *replaced* your A and B with new commits; call them AA and BB.

Now (5) you try to push dev. But the remote dev still has the old A and B. And your local dev doesn't! So the remote dev has commits that you don't have in your local dev, and the push is rejected. You cannot push without force unless your history is a continuation of the remote's history — and it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much makes sense. And in my above case when remote dev has A and B, and my local dev has A, B, C, how can I update the remote dev with the rebased A', B', C' and eventually update the master ?

Comment: Only by pushing with force. But it's a terrible idea because dev is evidently shared with others; if you force push dev, they will be furious at you. What was the reason for the rebase anyway? If the idea was to reduce the likelihood of conflicts when merging dev into master, what you should have done is merge master into dev (and resolve any conflicts as part of that). Or maybe there was no real reason for it.

Comment: So in our repo, the rule is to do rebase always to manage commit history cleanly. What is the best solution in my above case if I want to do rebase against master? Should I just delete the remote dev branch and create a MR again?

Comment: A repo where you can just download a branch with someone else's commits and directly add your own commits has no "rules".

Comment: So correct approach here is to just merge current MR, and then I should start from the updated master?

Comment: I don't know what you should do. Your question was about a thing that keeps happening to you. "I faced this issue for many times, so I want to share with you to get what's wrong with my approach."  I've tried to explain that. If you rebase a pushed branch you will have to force the next push. And I've explained why. My advice is: don't do that. And I don't believe that it is the "rule" to do so.